# unable to join nodes to Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am unable to join the nodes to my cluster.I have created kubernetes cluster master and node in my AWS environment using terraform tool.I am able to create the `Master(Kube-master)` and `single node(Kube-node)` but my other two nodes (`kude-node1` and `kube-node2`) were unable to join in cluster.

```
core@master ~ $ ./kubectl get no
NAME LABELS STATUS
10.0.0.31 kubernetes.io/hostname=10.0.0.31 Ready

core@master ~ $ ./kubectl version

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"0", GitVersion:"v1.0.1", GitCommit:"6a5c06e3d1eb27a6310a09270e4a5fb1afa93e74", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.7", GitCommit:"e4e6878293a339e4087dae684647c9e53f1cf9f0", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial that you followed or the tool that you used? You didn't provide much information to help anyone debug your issue. In the mean time, take a look at `/var/log/kubelet.log` on the nodes to see what is different between `Kube-node` and the two nodes that aren't working.

Comment: actually i have partially followed this guide by implementing my changes in master and nodes yml file. https://thepracticalsysadmin.com/create-a-kubernetes-cluster-on-aws-and-coreos-with-terraform/   .Here is the link to get the master and nodes yml files. (https://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/7J0PLsQrTUvfuPrDPO%2BqLNfB3GAQMwUY)

Answer (score 0):

The guide that you linked to was written 10 months ago and says

> NOTE:  This method seems to be broken as of the 0.14.2 release of
>   Kubernetes.

so I'm not surprised that you are having issues.

You may want to find a more recent example using terraform such as https://github.com/ericandrewlewis/kubernetes-via-terraform or getting it touch with the author of https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/21275.